# how to merge multiple text files using bash and preserving column order

Tags: bash, merge, text-files

I'm new to bash, I have a folder in which there are many text files among them there's a group which are named namefile-0, namefile-1,... namefile-100. I need to merge these file all in a new file. The format of each of these files is: header and 3 columns of data.

It is very important that the format of the new file is:
3 * 100 columns of data respecting the order of the columns (123123123...).

I don't mind if the header is also repeated or not.

I'm also willing, in case it was necessary, to place all these files in a folder in which no other files are present.

- I've tried to do something like this:

```
for i in {1..100}
do 
paste `echo "namefile$i"` >> `echo "b"
done
```

which prints only the first file into b.

- I've also tried to do this:

```
STR=""
for i in {1..100}
do
    STR=$STR"namefile"$i" "
done
paste $STR > b
```

which prints everything but does not preserve the order of the columns.

Comment: Hi Enjolras, welcome to stacoverflow. Your question attempts to provide a good amount of detail but still we can't help you solve it unless you show how your file looks like. We need to know what delimeter separates the columns.

Comment: the columns are separated by single space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mention what delimeter separates columns in your file.

Assuming the columns are separated by a single space,

```
paste -d' ' namefile-* > newfile
```

Other conditions like existence of other similar files or directories in the working directory, stripping of headers etc can also be tackled but some more information needs to be provided in the question.

Comment: @Enjolras, can you show how any of your text file looks like and what is the output of `paste namefile-* > newfile` in your question

Comment: I'm sorry, I just realised it worked (the columns looked messed up but they get read correctly by a program which reads columns!), thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

```sh
paste namefile-{0..100} >combined
```

Answer (score 0):

```
paste namefile* > new_file_name
```

Comment: It wouldn't preserve column order.

Comment: Odd, works when I ran a test. Can you post some sample data?